# Linear transformation from $R^3$ to $R^2$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Find the matrix of the linear transformation $T\colon {\Bbb R}^3 \to {\Bbb R}^2$ such that

$T(1,1,1) = (1,1)$, $T(1,2,3) = (1,2)$, $T(1,2,4) = (1,4)$.

So far, I have only dealt with transformations in the same R. Any help?

Comment: The idea remains the same once you fix a basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$. The only difference you'll see is that earlier you would be getting square matrices. Here you'll get a $2\times 3$ matrix. Thus in general $T:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^m$ yields a $m \times n$ matrix. Can you see why?

Answer (score 3):

Group your 3 constraints into a single one:

$$\tag{1}T.\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}1&1&1\\1&2&2\\1&3&4\end{pmatrix}}_{M}=\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}1&1&1\\1&2&4\end{pmatrix}}_{N}$$

(where the point means matrix product).

(1) is equivalent to $T=N.M^{-1},$ which is a $2 \times 3$ matrix.

Up to you for the last calculations.

You should find $\begin{pmatrix}1& \ \ 0&0\\2&-3&2\end{pmatrix}.$

Comment: Why compute $M^{-1}$ ? We can simply use elementary linear combinaisons for get $T(e_3)$, and then it is easy to conclude.

Comment: "Because it gives the simplest explanation" (and the easiest way to give the computation to be done to a computer), I would say.

Answer (score 0):

Hint : $T(0,0,1) = (0,2)$ so the last column of the matrix is $\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix}$.

Do you see how to find it ? Do you see how to continue ?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
Try finding $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$, $e$, $f$ such that:
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
a & b & c \\
d & e & f \\
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
1\\
1\\
1
\end{array}
\right)
=
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
1\\
1
\end{array}
\right)
$$
What other matrix equations can you form?